# How to keep changes in form after failed update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, model-view-controller, captcha

I have a quite standard Ruby-on-Rails form using [Simple-Captcha](https://github.com/pludoni/simple-captcha). The following update method only updates the attributes in case of correctly typed captcha:

```
@place = Place.find(params[:id])
if simple_captcha_valid?
  @place.update_attributes(params)
else
  flash.now[:danger] = 'Captcha not valid!'
  render :edit
end
```

When a wrong captcha is sent, the form gets rerendered with the original model attributes (changes are overwritten). How can I keep the changes in the form in those cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to reinitialize your `@place` object with any parameters you want to keep.  Something like this:

`if simple_captcha_valid?
  @place.update_attributes(params)
else
  @place.assign_attributes(params)
  flash.now[:danger] = 'Captcha not valid!'
  render :edit
end`